# Converting a file into ByteString literal in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Let's say I have a complicated object that's generated by non-trivial operations. I can serialize that object into a ByteString and write that Bytestring to a  file. Then I can open that file and deserialize it back to the same complicated object.

Now I'd like to hardcode the contents of that file in Haskell code so that I can "open" that file without dealing with IO.

How can I convert the contents of a file into a ByteString literal?

Here is a code example in case that makes things more clear

```
someComplicatedObject :: MyDataType
someComplicatedObject = ...

serialized :: ByteString
serialized = serialize someComplicatedObject

serialized_literal :: ByteString
serialized_literal = "...." -- <- what goes here?

main :: IO
main = do
  writeFile "myfile" serialized
  -- at this point, I want to copy the contents of "myfile" and paste it into `serialized_literal`
  fromFile <- readFile "myfile"
  
  -- expect the following to by true
  print $ serialized == fromFile
  print $ fromFile == serialized_literal
```

Comment: I tried copy and pasting the file contents, escaping it, and pasting it as a haskell `String` and that definitely didn't work. I tried it has a `Text` and calling `encodeUtf8` on it and that also did not work. The deserializer I'm using fails.

which is besides the point, I want the ByteString literal to be the same as what I would get if I were to open the file that had the ByteString written to it

Comment: You can use template haskell to "embed" the content...

Comment: See https://hackage.haskell.org/package/file-embed-0.0.15.0/docs/Data-FileEmbed.html

Answer (score 5):

Probably the easiest way to do this is to "embed" the file using *template Haskell*.

You can for example use the [**`file-embed`** package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/file-embed). Template Haskell allows you to run a Haskell function at compile time. The [**`embedFile :: FilePath -> Q Exp`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/file-embed-0.0.15.0/docs/Data-FileEmbed.html#v:embedFile) will in this case open the file and convert the content into a `ByteString` literal.

You thus can run this with:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Data.FileEmbed(embedFile)
import Data.ByteString

serialized_literal :: ByteString
serialized_literal = $(embedFile "myfile")
```

The content of the file will thus be embedded in the executable. That means that if you change `myfile` *after* you compiled the program, `serialized_literal` will still hold the content of the file *before* you modified the file.